# Open source license

Tags: 14.04, open-source

How should I license some desktop icons and shell bash files as open sorce software? I am creating and going to package them for Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This highly depends on your opinion on what you are comfortable with.

Comment: Any ideas as I have never do this before

Comment: Open sorce but that not able to make edits to the code and must have my name a seatless in the sorce code of every file

Comment: @Jhondoe What sense do you ever put into these ten letters: ‘open source’ if you are going to strip your licensees from the right to **modify** your work? I saw quite a lot cases of misunderstandings of that silly term ‘open source’ – people usually believed that they could prohibit commercial usage of their product or selling it and still call it ‘open source’, but you are the first person I met who thinks that ‘open source’ work could be unmodifiable.

Answer (score 2):

On the question of **Free Software** vs **Open Source**, you might want to have a look at the [Philosphy of the GNU Project](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/philosophy.en.html), particularly at Richard Stallman's [Why Open Source misses the point of Free Software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/open-source-misses-the-point.en.html).

If you rather prefer to watch and listen, have a look at Richard Stallman's most recent (2014-12-29) talk [Freedom in your computer and in the net](http://media.ccc.de/browse/congress/2014/31c3_-_6123_-_en_-_saal_1_-_201412291130_-_freedom_in_your_computer_and_in_the_net_-_richard_stallman.html), given at 31C3.

You wrote:

> Open sorce but that not able to make edits to the code and must have my name a seatless in the sorce code of every file

That would exclude the **GNU GPL**, since you want to deny the freedom to distribute modified versions of your work.

In principle, a conceivable licence then would be **Creative Commons** license, namely [Attribution-NoDerivatives 4.0 International (CC BY-ND 4.0)](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/4.0/).

A package licensed under these conditions will never make it to Ubuntu **main**, for which [LIcensing](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing) explicitly makes clear:

> Must allow modification and distribution of modified copies under the same licence. Just having the source code does not convey the same freedom as having the right to change it. Without the ability to modify software, the Ubuntu community cannot support software, fix bugs, translate it, or improve it.

Comment: That would exclude *any* free / libre / ‘open source’ license actually.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov True! The *NoDerivatives* limitation might have a reason for artwork (or not), but it is a stupid idea for code or for the publication of scientific research. Imagine to tell people not to apply your published experimental findings on their our research: WHAT!? :D